# issue with amazon cloudsearch search with location

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

my problem is  amazon cloudSearch  with location ..

when i use rank expression for search product with location found this error

```
       ["info"]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (4) {
    ["rid"]=>
    string(80) "ee6c7090a20a654dbfd52a5f2ce0eeb96e766f609a8889bc1af02ab95e4065a6ce8ed690aa624373"
    ["time-ms"]=>
    int(4)
    ["cpu-time-ms"]=>
    int(0)
    ["messages"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
        ["severity"]=>
        string(7) "warning"
        ["code"]=>
        string(27) "CS-RankExpressionParseError"
        ["message"]=>
        string(328) "Could not parse rank expression (rank-geo=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(22345345-534534),2) Math.pow(Math.abs(934593495-34534534),2))): The ANTLR parser returned: -memory-(1)  : error 10 : Missing token, at offset 47
    near [Index: 0 (Start: 0-Stop: 0) ='', type<7> Line: 1 LinePos:47]
     : Missing RPAREN 
"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#18 (3) {
        ["severity"]=>
        string(7) "warning"
        ["code"]=>
        string(41) "CS-InvalidFieldOrRankAliasInRankParameter"
        ["message"]=>
        string(47) "Unable to create score object for rank 'bineet'"
      }
    }
  }
```

while my search request url is

htp://www.search_endpoint."/search?bq=".urlencode($term)."&rank=geo&rank-geo=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(22345345 - 534534),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(934593495 - 34534534),2))&size=$size&start=$start&return-fields=".implode(',',$return_fields

where i am doing wrong  ?
without rank expression it is working fine . 
i think error is in  define expression for location but could not found any other solution 
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found  solution for this by using

```
  &rank-geo=urlencode('Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(22345345 - doc.latitude),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(934593495 - doc.longitude),2))')
```

this is rank-expression example

you can use custom rank expression in amazon cloud-search with two way

1. Make a new rank expression in amazon cloud-search console admin panel and define expression 
                       ie mathematical expression and in search url simply append that rank expression name only  like bellow

   &rank=geo   // geo rank expression should be define on cloud-search console admin panel
2. Second  way is include rank name and expession in dynamic way like that in search url

   ```
    &rank=distancesearch&rank-distancesearch=urlencode('Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(22345345 - doc.latitude),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(934593495 - doc.longitude),2))')
   ```

   in this way no need to make a rank expression on amazon cloudSearch console admin panel